# Interact with a base file from the file that is being imported

Tags: python-3.x, class, pyqt5, python-import

Still trying to figure out how exactly imports work in Python and ran into a problem I was hoping could be solved. I am using PyQt5 and currently have three files called fileA, fileB, and fileC. fileA imports a class from fileB and fileB imports a class from fileC. This is all to say that I cannot import fileA into fileC without encountering a circular import. What I want to do is on a button press that occurs in fileC, to refresh the class located in fileA.

fileA looks like:

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
    etc...
```

and what I am trying to do in fileC is:

```
def on_click(self):
    Window.refresh()
```

So essentially I want to be able to refresh a window on a button press from a different file. Any advice would be much appreciated whether class related or PyQt5 related. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically it wouldn't be possible without importing file A into C. 
When you import the files you should just declare the classes functions etc. And in main file you should just call those function.

If you are using three files for three windows, it's alright just make sure you call the functions in main file.